# My websites html files does not open because of Web API web.config file

Tags: asp.net, xml, api, web-config, hosting

My websites html files does not open because of Web API web.config file.

I am trying to host my website on Plesk. I put my frontend (HTML CSS JS) files in the httpdocs folder and there was no problem opening them (I could open them with the URL: `fadaeitrading.com/Home.html`). But then I published my Web API in visual studio and also put it in the same httpdocs folder. Now I can access the Web API with the URL example of: `fadaeitrading.com/api/Product/GetProducts` (Product is the controller name and `GetProducts` is the endpoint) but I can not access the html files I get the `ERROR 404`. I am almost sure its because of the Web APIs web.config file but I don't know how to fix it (maybe someone can make it so that when the URL has `api/` the Web API works). I will provide the web.config files content here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\LAV.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4447276A-7814-4EFD-B2D8-457F7A8B94B4-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just needed to change the:

```
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

to

```
<add name="aspNetCore" path="api/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```